# list all combobox items in one messagebox

Tags: c#, for-loop, combobox

I am trying to list all combobox items in one messagebox. but all i get is every item comes up in its own messagebox. I know the messagebox needs to be outside the loop but when i do that it says the variable is unassigned. Any help would be great.

private void displayYachtTypesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

```
       string yachtTypesString;

        for (int indexInteger = 0; indexInteger < typeComboBox.Items.Count; indexInteger++)

        {
            yachtTypesString=typeComboBox.Items[indexInteger].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(yachtTypesString);
        }

       }
```

Comment: The problem is you need to assing **string yachtTypesString;** to a value in your case a empty string **string yachtTypesString = "";** and it will work

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this,

```
    StringBuilder yachtTypesString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int indexInteger = 0; indexInteger < typeComboBox.Items.Count; indexInteger++)
    {
        yachtTypesString.AppendLine(typeComboBox.Items[indexInteger].ToString());
    }
    MessageBox.Show(yachtTypesString.ToString());
```

NOTE: Do not do string concatenation with a string, use StringBuilder object as doing it in a string creates a new instance.

Comment: There will be an *empty line* at the bottom of the `MessageBox`, since the the last `yachtTypesString.AppendLine` adds carrige return

Answer (score 1):

You can try using *Linq*:

```
  MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, typeComboBox.Items.Cast<String>()));
```

and let it do all the work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            string yachtTypesString="";

    for (int indexInteger = 0; indexInteger < typeComboBox.Items.Count; indexInteger++)

    {
        yachtTypesString=yachtTypesString +  typeComboBox.Items[indexInteger].ToString();

    }

     MessageBox.Show(yachtTypesString);
```

Comment: you're gonna be wasting a lot of string instance with that, use string builder for processes like this.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this worked here I just had to add an Environment.NewLine so they would all display on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

list all combobox items in one messagebox

Please play  with Below code To Get Combobox all Text

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dtcheck = new DataTable();
            dtcheck.Columns.Add("ID");
            dtcheck.Columns.Add("Name");
            for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
            {
                dtcheck.Rows.Add(i, "A" + i);
            }

```
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dtcheck;


    }
}

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string MessageText = string.Empty;

        foreach(object item in comboBox1.Items)
        {
           DataRowView row = item as DataRowView;

           MessageText += row["Name"].ToString() + "\n";
        }

        MessageBox.Show(MessageText, "ListItems", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```